# "Я приду примерно к семи" — нет ли речевой ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

> Я приду примерно к семи.

Нет ли в этой фразе речевой ошибки? Мне кажется, "к семи" уже имеет оттенок неточного указания времени. Так, может быть, это плеоназм?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь какое-то другое противоречие. "**К семи**" я воспринимаю как "в семь или чуть раньше (с запасом на задержку в пути, но к семи *успею*)". "**Примерно (в семь)**" не обязывает "успеть к семи". Соответственно, два способа выражения времени прихода расходятся по смыслу, и даже возникает вопрос: не означает ли здесь "примерно", что на самом деле придут "к шести" или "к восьми" (как получится)? Если человек не уверен, получится лиу него прийти "к семи" (как он планирует), то вместо "примерно" может подойти "*ориентировочно* (как предварительная информация: я приду к семи, но если не смогу, дам знать заранее)".

Answer (score 1):

Таких "плеоназмов" в разговорной речи пруд пруди. Никакой речевой ошибки и тем более -противоречий" здесь нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы живете в большом городе, то прийти/приехать точно в семь  сложно, поэтому обычно указывается интервал: *я приду к семи*. Это означает *к семи или около этого* (обычно не позже семи).

*Прийти примерно (ориентировочно) к семи* ― это также *прийти ближе к семи или около семи*, но **неопределенность при указании времени увеличена.**

Поэтому коммуникативность сообщения соответствует норме (**здесь нет плеоназма**): вам говорят, что **время указано неточно.**